# Can linux change hardware functionality directly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, rgb

Edit: The chosen answer did not solve it for me but was the closest and maybe it could be of help to others.

I have a Lenovo Y720 laptop, which has han RGB keyboard. Unfortunately, the RGB only works on windows, because it requires a program called "Lenovo Nerve Sense", which controls the lights. Since this program is only available on windows, is it possible in any way to light up the keyboard on Ubuntu? I have tried every single thread out there, which refers to tcpi or thinkpads, xled, xset led, and all of these functions which doesn't work. Ubuntu actually can't even see that I got LEDs in my keyboard, it can only see caps lock and numlock, since those are on firmware level, while the keyboard backlight is not.

Is Linux able to make changes in the hardware, like finding some register for the RGB light? Lenovo will not help with this they said, neither port the program to Linux.

Comment: Yes, you can write software to control those LEDs from Linux. No, you cannot do it without documentation or reverse engineering the Windows application.

Comment: So in other words, it is impossible for me?

Comment: Unless you have some experience with low-level Windows programming and/or reverse engineering experience, it's close to impossible or at least very, **very** hard.

Comment: Oh well then, might just give up.

Comment: If it's an USB keyboard, google for "USB reverse engineering" - it's not that hard, and tools can be found easily now. If Lenovo was really nice (unlikely), it may even be in the HID descriptor... However, be prepared to invest a lot of time, and you'll have to read lots of technical standards etc.

Comment: It is a laptop i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible answer (may not apply to your specific machine):

On my Lenovo P50 on my stock Kubuntu 16.04:

- There is a directory `/proc/acpi/ibm/` in the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem (Lenovo inherited IBM's laptop brand)
- There are several files in that directory, including one named `/proc/acpi/ibm/kbdlight`
- `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/kbdlight` says:

  ```
  status:         0
  commands:       0, 1, 2
  ```
- then

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'echo 2 >/proc/acpi/ibm/kbdlight'
  ```

  actually lights up the keyboard (using `echo 1` dims it, and `echo 0` turns it off).

You may already have something similar on your laptop, so `cat` the files, and experiment. **Note:** the sudo command is a bit contrived because the more natural `sudo echo 2 >/proc/acpi/ibm/kbdlight` doesn't work since the redirection to `/proc/acpi/ibm/kbdlight` is done by your non-privileged userid.

PS: in addition, on my P50, the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> key combo does natively control the keyboard lights.

PPS: The underlying module is the [`thinkpad_acpi` driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt) which is now part of the Linux kernel (since late 2.6 versions) and seems actively maintained (additions in April to support the P50...). Note that the documentation says that the use of `/proc/acpi` is deprecated and one should use `/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/` instead.

Comment: Do you happen to know what kernel module makes this interface available (e.g. look at `lsmod` and make a guess, or look at `dmesg` after boot)? That information might be important for other people trying to make it work, if the kernel module doesn't recognize their hardware (yet).

Comment: @dirkt See augmented answer...